How do I properly make SDL not scale up the SDL window or the HTML canvas size in a WASM app?
I'm making a WASM program using SDL2 and Emscripten. It creates a 1000x1000 window using SDL_CreateWindow("scribbles", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, context.w, context.h, 0);. I have a very simple .html file I use with it that doesn't really do anything fancy. It doesn't define the canvas size.
The problem is that the canvas it creates in the webpage is way too big, and so are the graphics. It's all upscaled, maybe by around 1.5x. My browser is not zoomed in. I get the same problem in both Windows and WSL. I think it's upscaling because I have a 4K monitor so it has a high PPI.
If I include the SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI flag, then the graphics are actually the right size, but the canvas isn't. The canvas itself is still too big, and the extra space is colored in with pure black. If I set the width and height of the canvas in CSS to 1000x1000, it does nothing, unless SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI is used, in which case it makes the canvas smaller but it makes the graphics even smaller in the same proportion to the canvas (so there's still extra black area). If I set the canvas size to 500x500 (without SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI), it makes it smaller but not exactly the right size, and I don't know how to compute what size I have to scale it down for whatever system is running it.
SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI solves the problem perfectly for the non-web version of this program, on the other hand.
SDL_SetHintWithPriority(SDL_HINT_WINDOWS_DPI_AWARENESS, "unaware", SDL_HINT_OVERRIDE); does nothing.
What I want is for it to not automatically upscale and also to have the SDL window with the graphics displayed in it to be the same size as the canvas.
Oh, by the way, I've also tried using SDL3 with Emscripten instead of SDL2 to see if that eliminates the problem (assuming it's a bug that they might have fixed in the latest version, and assuming it's SDL's fault and not Emscripten's fault), but I couldn't figure out how to do it.
